# Un beau pangramme français

Tags: alphabet

Les pangrammes que l’on utilise couramment pour le français me déplaisent : « Portez ce vieux whisky au juge blond qui fume » nous renvoie à deux addictions et « Voix ambiguë d'un cœur qui, au zéphyr, préfère les jattes de kiwis »  nous assomme dans l'absurde.

Le pangramme anglais le plus courant : « The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog » ou encore « Sphinx of black quartz, judge my vow » me semblent meilleurs.

Quels pangrammes en langue française trouvez-vous agréables à lire ?

Comment: "fait moins sens" est probablement un anglicisme :-) "est moins compréhensible" serait plus courant?

Comment: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangramme a plusieurs exemples.

Comment: On peut en générer un sur l'ordi. Si j'arrive à trouver un bon dictionnaire online, j'essaierai peut-être. Quoique ce n'est peut-être pas si simple, pour en générer à la fois correct et plaisant.

Comment: "nous assomme dans l'absurde" - sent l'anglicisme à nouveau ("into oblivion?") hmmm - je dirais: "nous assomme (de) par son absurdité".

Comment: En voici un que j'ai inventé : *Dame, va t'abriter chez le joyeux kiné qui nage parfois le crawl.* Mais je ne sais pas si l'on peut dire qu'il est moins absurde que les autres.

Answer (score 1):

L'UIT utilise *Voyez le brick géant que j'examine près du wharf.*